# Matplotlib sum of colors as result of plot overlapping

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphics

When a plot overlapping occurs I would like to obtain the RGB sum of the colors instead of simply painting over the existing plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.scatter(0,1,s=1000,c='g')
plt.scatter(1,1,s=1000,c='g')
plt.scatter(1,1.01,s=1000,c='r')
plt.scatter(1,1.1,s=1000,c='g')
plt.scatter(2,1,s=1000,c='g')
```

This generates the following image:
[image]

But I would like to obtain the mathematical sum of the colors (255,0,0) + (0,255,0) = (255, 255, 0)

So like this:
[image]

I tried with the alpha parametter but it depends on which plot was first.

Comment: Alpha should work if both markers have alpha that is the same

Comment: I already tried it and it depends on which plot was plotted first @jody-klymak

Comment: This isn't really in the scope of matplotib because it would change based on your marker size. It sounds like you should define some spatial geometries and represent the areas and compute the intersections and symbolize the resulting geometries accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure if you have a different problem this relates to, but you don't have physical data between those intersections of those points so you can't condition the geometry to change the color. I believe using 'alpha' is your only option but it won't add RBG values.